# MySQL_Workbench Docker Ubuntu Linux

Tags: docker-compose, ubuntu-22.04

i'm using the docker-compose file from https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/mysql-workbench.

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  mysql-workbench:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/mysql-workbench:latest
    container_name: mysql-workbench
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Etc/UTC
    volumes:
      - /path/to/config:/config
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 3001:3001
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    restart: unless-stopped
```

when i issue `docker-compose up -d` i get an ERROR

```
mysql-workbench    | [custom-init] No custom files found, skipping...
mysql-workbench    | _XSERVTransmkdir: ERROR: euid != 0,directory /tmp/.X11-unix will not be created.
mysql-workbench    | 
mysql-workbench    | Xvnc KasmVNC 1.2.0 - built Oct 26 2023 21:53:23
mysql-workbench    | Copyright (C) 1999-2018 KasmVNC Team and many others (see README.me)
mysql-workbench    | See http://kasmweb.com for information on KasmVNC.
mysql-workbench    | Underlying X server release 12014000, The X.Org Foundation
mysql-workbench    | 
mysql-workbench    | [ls.io-init] done.
mysql-workbench    | Obt-Message: Xinerama extension is not present on the server
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tested if it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it
go to mysql-workbench bash => sudo docker exec -it <container_id> bash
then run these commands

- sudo apt-get install xorg
- sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg
- sudo apt-get install libxinerama1
- export DISPLAY=:0.0
- sudo apt-get update
  then it will work

or use this image for mysql-workbench

- image: lscr.io/linuxserver/mysql-workbench:8.0.29

Comment: This doesn't really sound like a solution. It seems the original docker image starts a VNC server. Did you attempt to connect to that VNC server?

Comment: yes i was have the same problem and these command solve this problem for me

Comment: thanks a lot  
i just used the proposed image and it works  
strange behavior i would say

Comment: how?
I recommend you to open the URL in a browser other than Chrome